# Alternatives to proof by exhaustion

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification

Let  = {−2, −1,0,1,2},  = {0,1,4} and  = {−4, −3, −2, −1,0,1,2,3,4}.

Prove ∀ ∈  (( ∈ ) ↔ (^ ∈ )).

Proof by exhaustion:

1. x ∈ $C ⋂ A$ = {-2,-1,0,1,2}

   1.1 (-2)^2 = 4,  (2)^2 =4, 4 ∈ B

   1.2 (-1) ^2 =1, (1) ^2 = 1 , 1 ∈ B

   1.3 (0) ^ 2 = 0 , 0 ∈ B
2. x in C, and x^2 in B = {0,1,4}

   2.1 √0  = 0 , 0 ∈ A

   2.2  x^2 = 1 , x = 1,-1 ∈ A

   2.3  x^2 = 4 , x = 2,-2 ∈ A

So ∀ ∈  (( ∈ ) ↔ (^ ∈ )) is true

My question is: for the part 2,how do I write the statement for all x in C such that its square is also in B ??

And is there any other way to prove besides proof by exhaustion??

Comment: Sometimes there are clever ways, but for finite sets where the elements are simply listed, proof by exhaustion is actually the most natural approach.